# how to make row editable after selecting option from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make my table row editable when i will select edit option from dropdown box. Previously it was woring fine but that time i used Edit button inside all row. But now i have made edit button by putting into dropdown. but now it is not working. I am not able to find any error in my code but still it is not working.
 my html table is

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-hover"  id="myTable" >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Parameter Names</th>
                <th>Parameter Values</th>
                <th>Remarks</th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Carter</td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
                <td>Peter</td>
                <td>Parker</td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
          <ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="display:none" >
            <li><a tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-mini btnEdit" >Edit</a></li>
          </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function ($, window) {

            $.fn.contextMenu = function (settings) {

                return this.each(function () {

                    // Open context menu
                    $(this).on("contextmenu", function (e) {
                        //open menu
                        $(settings.menuSelector)
                            .data("invokedOn", $(e.target))
                            .show()
                            .css({
                                position: "absolute",
                                left: getLeftLocation(e),
                                top: getTopLocation(e)
                            })
                            .off('click')
                            .on('click', function (e) {
                                $(this).hide();

                                var $invokedOn = $(this).data("invokedOn");
                                var $selectedMenu = $(e.target);

                                settings.menuSelected.call(this, $invokedOn, $selectedMenu);
                        });

                        return false;
                    });

                    //make sure menu closes on any click
                    $(document).click(function () {
                        $(settings.menuSelector).hide();
                    });
                });

                function getLeftLocation(e) {
                    var mouseWidth = e.pageX;
                    var pageWidth = $(window).width();
                    var menuWidth = $(settings.menuSelector).width();

                    // opening menu would pass the side of the page
                    if (mouseWidth + menuWidth > pageWidth &&
                        menuWidth < mouseWidth) {
                        return mouseWidth - menuWidth;
                    } 
                    return mouseWidth;
                }        

                function getTopLocation(e) {
                    var mouseHeight = e.pageY;
                    var pageHeight = $(window).height();
                    var menuHeight = $(settings.menuSelector).height();

                    // opening menu would pass the bottom of the page
                    if (mouseHeight + menuHeight > pageHeight &&
                        menuHeight < mouseHeight) {
                        return mouseHeight - menuHeight;
                    } 
                    return mouseHeight;
                }
            };
        })(jQuery, window);

        $("#myTable td").contextMenu({
            menuSelector: "#contextMenu",
            menuSelected: function (invokedOn, selectedMenu) {
                var msg = "You selected the menu item '" + selectedMenu.text() +
                    "' on the value '" + invokedOn.text() + "'";
            }
        });
        function Save() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent();
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdPhone.html(tdPhone.children("input[type=text]").val());
    tdEmail.html(tdEmail.children("input[type=text]").val());

    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
};

function Edit() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent();
    var tdParameterName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdParameterValues = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdRemarks = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdButtons="";
    tdParameterName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='" + tdParameterName.html()
            + "'/>");
    tdParameterValues.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='" + tdParameterValues.html()
            + "'/>");
    tdRemarks.html("<input type='text' id='txtEmail' value='" + tdRemarks.html()
            + "'/>");
    tdButtons.html("<a class='btn btn-mini btnSave'>Save</a>");
    $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
};

function Delete() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent();
    par.remove();
}; 


$(function() {
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
});
        </script>
```

Basically i am enabling right click menu. After clicking right dropdown box will open. whne i will click edit button then my row will become editable. I have added jquery for contextMenu and for edit button. Sorry for making code very dirty but currently i am practicing and also i am new in this.

Comment: can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: if you make this into a fiddle people will probably help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/552bk6cs/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output that the console gives you. Clicking edit results in `TypeError: tdButtons.html is not a function` which results from the two lines:

```
var tdButtons="";
```

and

```
tdButtons.html("<a class='btn btn-mini btnSave'>Save</a>");
```

So you are creating an empty string and trying to use it as if it was a jQuery object. You will need to change theses lines to get it to work again.

Comment: can you change the fiddle to show your updated version?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update on fiddle. now you can see.

Comment: Can you post the link?!

Comment: ok so the problem now is that your `var par = $(this).parent().parent();` selector is not matching any elements. You need to change this so that it matches the corresponding `tr` again

Comment: can you help me to do that because i tried to do that but i could not?